# rails routes.rb, why routing insist to have a get specified when it's only a post request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I created a api method for post.  I specify in routes.rb that it should be called via :post only, but when I call the api through the browser it complains that it missing the GET routes.  What's wrong?

```
class Api::XyzsController < ApiController

  # POST /api/create_xyz
  def create_xyz

    product = Product.find(params[:rpt_id])
    Xyz.create!(:product_id => product.id ,
              :status => 'open',....)

    render :json => {:message => 'Submitted.'}, :status => :ok
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
...
namespace 'api' do
      match 'create_xyz' => 'xyzs#create_xyz', :via => [:post]
end
```

post on the browser,  http://localhost/api/create_xyz?rpt_id=123
get error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/api/create_xyz
```

route generated:

```
api_report_xyz POST     /api/report_xyz(.:format)  {:format=>"json", :action=>"report_xyz", :controller=>"api/xyzs"}
```

if I add a get to via in routes.rb, it fixes it.  But I don't understand why it insists to have a get when it's a post method call....

Comment: How are you actually trying to send this post request?

Comment: I think there's a big misunderstanding happening here. Using a link (a href) or a redirect_to will ALWAYS be a GET request. there is nothing you can do to make it a post. This is not a limitation of rails. This is how browsers and HTTP work.

Answer (score 0):

The :via option doesn't force the request to become a POST if it is a GET.  It merely restricts the incoming requests to be POST requests.  The request still needs to be constructed as a POST.

Comment: How? is the way I specify the url is incorrect?  What should I be then? [link]http://localhost/api/create_xyz?rpt_id=123

Comment: If you are just making a regular link with a query string appended to it, that will issue a GET request.  To make a POST request, you would either construct a form with method="post" as an attribute of the form, or if you are using the rails link_to method then you can use the option :method => :post to turn it into a POST request.  be warned that using the :method => :post option with link_to is actually a little bit of rails magic and will turn the link into a form.

Comment: huh, that's interesting.  However, this is a api controller class, it's a action inside the controller that I'm calling.  There isn't really a form associate with this.  As you can see above, within the action, it's requesting a parameter, that's all.  No form at at all.  Is there a way to enforce POST in the controller action?

Comment: if it's requesting a parameter, and not setting a parameter, why do you want it to be a POST?

Answer (score 0):

The setting :via => :post in your routes file just means that there is only a POST route, no others.

It does not control what people try to send to your application.  It does however mean if someone sends a GET request that your app will say "no route" because you have only got a POST route.

I understand you have no associated view and that this is for an API, but however you are testing this is sending a GET request.  The type of request that comes through is decided by the originator of the request, not your app (assuming coming from external).  Change the way you are testing or how the originator is sending the request to be a POST and your problem will go away.